# Trying to extract information from HTML response using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

i am trying to grape just Email(myemail@hotmail.com) from my HTML response using cheerio and puppeteer modules. but i am getting different things that i dont need to use all of them at all. 
Its placed in the Class p2 in td/tr.
while putting tr as parameter in the

this is how my code looks like:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://mywebsite.com';

puppeteer
  .launch()
  .then(function(browser) {
    return browser.newPage();
  })
  .then(function(page) {
    return page.goto(url).then(function() {
      return page.content();
    });
  })
  .then(function(html) {
    $('tr', html).each(function() {
        // putting all the result into the list

      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    //handle error
  });
```

i am geeting this output:

> Mobile  Post box    Circuit
>
> myemail@hotmail.com
>   E-mail myemail@hotmail.com 
>   Manager 
>   Secretary
>
> i do need just myemail@hotmail.com

this is my HTML table:

```
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="p1">E-mail</td>
                    <td class="p2">
                            <span style="float: none; word-wrap: break-word;"> <a href="mailto:myEmal@hotmail.com"> myEmal@hotmail.com
                                    <div style="padding-right: 2px; background-position: -115px -434px; height: 14px !important; float: right" class="ico"></div>
                            </a>
                            </span>
                        </td>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use RegEx?It looks like a decent solution to this problem.

Comment: The HTML doesn't look like the actual HTML, as it doesn't have `Manager Secretary` anywhere in it.

Comment: @Keith this is a part of the html table

Comment: Indeed, and the part were interested in has been removed.. :)

Comment: @while trying to put tr the response send me all tr of my whole html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your HTML the simplest way would be this:

```
$('td.p2 a[href^=mailto]', html).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text().trim());
});
```

Note that you need to close the browser after scraping:

```
let _browser;

puppeteer
  .launch()
  .then(function(browser) {
    _browser = browser; // <-- memorize browser reference
    return _browser.newPage();
  })
  .then(function(page) {
    return page.goto(url).then(function() {
      return page.content();
    });
  })
  .then(function(html) {
    $('td.p2 a[href^=mailto]', html).each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text().trim());
    });
  })
  .then(function(){
    _browser.close() // <-- use it to close the browser
  })
```

If you're running node 8+, it's better to use async/await for such scripts.

Comment: it looks like after providing my email@hotmail.com the process comes into a infinity loop. how do i can end the process after providing my email? alex@/Desktop/scd
$ node app.js
email@hotmail.com
//does not stop looping

Comment: sorry that i am asking to much but i am just a beginner.after closing the browser, i have a big blank text with my email. how to remove it? 
alex@~/Desktop/scd
$ node app.js
myemail@hotmail.com

alex@~/Desktop/scd

Comment: Remove console.log which prints it?

Comment: i need to integrate this function with node-mailer function so that i grab this email(var result = $(this).text().trim()) and passing it into the function of nodemailer e.g sendmail(result) while trying this the result i got from your Method is blank text,  but when trying with console.log i get the correct result, why?

Comment: Please show how you do it, and since it's another issue, you should really open a new question about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting contents within the td of that class.

```
console.log($(this).find('td.p2').text());
```

Comment: the problem is that i have many different classes with name p2 so that i am getting all of the p2 results. ;( is there another thread of how to doing this?